# show all products which has discounts (specific price) - Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop

I'm looking for a way to display all products that has specific prices to them, and display like  any other category page.

I've created the front controller and the class in a module.

I'm not really into sql so I want a query that would fetch all data in one place, like id_image, id_product, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find all products with special price at PricesDrop controller. The default URL is

`/prices-drop`